# Does every divergent series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ (with $a_n>0$) grow like $\int a_n dn$ in the limit $n \to \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

From the definition of Euler's constant I knew that the following is true

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}-\log N \right)=\gamma$$

I decided to check for other similar divergent series with Mathematica and got the following results:

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-2\sqrt{N} \right)=\zeta \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)=-1.46035$$

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}-\frac{3}{2} N^{2/3} \right)=\zeta \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)=-0.97336$$

And for the convergent series this is trivially true, since any integral of $a_n$ is $0$ in the limit:

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{N} \right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

I think this may be why the integral convergence test works.

> So does this work for every divergent series? Can we just 'regularize' all of them in this way?
>
> And by the way, why isn't $\zeta(1)=\gamma$?

Comment: Try $a_n = 2+(-1)^n$ -- what do you take as the integral there?

Comment: $\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s=1$ (roughly speaking, $\zeta(1)=\infty$).

Comment: @ClementC, good example. I could use $(-1)^x=e^{i \pi x}$ though

Comment: @Clement Just linearly interpolate between $n$ and $n+1$.

Comment: @A.S. Isn't that "cheating" a bit? By definition, this will give you (if I'm not mistaken) $\int_{n}^{n+1} f(x)dx = a_n + \frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right)$ for any possible sequence $(a_n)_n$ and by construction you'd get the result wanted (more or less) because of the telescopic series.

Comment: @Clement If you start with a sequence $a_n$, then I don't see how simple linear extrapolation is "cheating" and the fact that we get the wanted result is only confirmation for its appropriateness. Otherwise, if we start with $a_n=a(n)$ (of which your example is not an example of) for some $a:R\to R$, then we at least need $\frac {a(n)}{\int_{n-1}^n a(x)}\,dx\sim 1$ (for $\sim$) or $\Theta(1)$. The former requires sub-exponential growth and the latter not super exponential growth of $a(x)$.

Comment: @A.S. I reckon I'm just still trying to make sense of the question: given a sequence $(a_n)_n$, there is not a unique function $f$ to extend it to the reals... for some choices of $f$, the OP's question seems trivial, for some others a bit less (in your suggestion, you choose $f$ to be continuous by construction, for instance).

Comment: This might help.  The leading term of the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_formula) is $$\sum_{n=1}^Nf(n)=\int_0^Nf(x)\,dx$$for any real -valued or complex-valued continuous function $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for each of the series you tried, $a_n=f(n)$ for a decreasing continuous function $f(x)$ on $[1,\infty)$. In general, there is no reason for an arbitrary sequence $a_n$ to have such regular behavior. But in this special case, the sum and integral are very closely related by the integral test, as you've observed.